# Using like in Teradata for multiple values

Tags: teradata

I have a requirement where I have to select multiple usernames from a table based on like condition.

```
UserName_Table:
Username_column
--------
Nicky
Nolan
Megan
Fox
Federar
Fager
```

Query will be:

```
Select Username_column 
from UserName_Table 
where Username_column like Any ('N%','Megan');
```

this will give the result:

```
Username_column
--------
Nicky
Nolan
Megan
```

Here comes the question: I want to put ('N%','Megan') in a table which will be populated from business users. Say table User_Filter.

```
User_Filter_Table:
User_Filter_column
-----------------
N%
Megan
```

I have changed my query as below to get the filter from table.

```
Select Username_column 
from UserName_Table 
where Username_column like Any (Select User_Filter_column from User_Filter_Table);
```

Weirdly this gives below result:

```
Username_column
--------
Megan
```

Why the query is skipping N%?

Could anyone please help?

Appreciate the help in Advance.

Thanks
Santhosh

Comment: What's the datatype of `User_Filter_column`?

Comment: It is char datatype.

Comment: I Tried below query weirdly I am seeing results what I want to see. Select Username_column 
from UserName_Table 
where Username_column like Any (Select trim(OREPLACE(User_Filter_column, '%', ' '))||'%'from User_Filter_Table);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LIKE` does *not* ignore trailing blanks.

```
'Nicky' LIKE 'N% ' -> false
'Nicky ' LIKE 'N% ' -> true
```

Change the datatype to `VarChar` or add a `TRIM`:

```
where Username_column like Any (Select TRIM(TRAILING FROM User_Filter_column) from User_Filter_Table);
```